# Combinatorial interpretation of double factorial.

Tags: combinatorics, factorial, combinatorial-proofs

Using some basic algebra (and proved afterwards using induction), I found that:

$$ 1 \cdot 3 \cdot ... (2n-1) = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n \cdot n!}$$

After a bit of research, I found out that this is known as the 'double factorial', is there a combinatorial interpretation/proof for this result?

Comment: It counts in two different ways the number of ways to divide $2n$ people into $n$ teams of $2$ people.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That is an explanation of the RHS, but I am unsure of how this relates to the LHS. In other words, why is the number of ways to partition a set of size $2n$ into $n$ sets of size $2$ equal to the product of the odd integers. In isolation, what does the product of the odd numbers count? Is it the permutations of a set such that no element retains it's original position?

Comment: Technically, the double factorial also includes $2\cdot 4\cdots 2n$. What you have here is $(2n-1)!!$.

Comment: The number of pairings of $2n$ elements is $2n-1$ times the number of pairings of $2n-2$ elements. Then work by induction @GridleyQuayle

Comment: Line up the people in ascending order of age, or beauty, or student number. The youngest person has $2n-1$ choices for her team mate. For each of these choices, the youngest person not yet chosen has $2n-3$ choices for her team mate. For each of these choices, the youngest person not yet on a team has $2n-5$ choices, and so on.  I think of this product as the natural way to count the number of divisions into teams, and the "right-hand side" way as less obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

André Nicolas gives the clue, "It counts in two different ways the number of ways to divide 2n people into n teams of 2 people."

**The left-hand side**

Consider the following procedure:

- Select the youngest person who has not yet been put in a two-person team.
- Match them with another so far unselected person.

This produces $1\cdot(2n-1)\cdot1\cdot(2n-3)\cdot\ldots\cdot(3)\cdot1\cdot(1)$, which is the left-hand side. The procedure can give any matching, and from any matching we can reconstruct the choices we made.

**The right-hand side**

Suppose we ask the two-person teams to form a line. There are $2n$ persons, and thus $(2n)!$ possible lines. But for any given ordering, the pairs can be reordered (with the left person remaining on the left) in $n!$ ways, and the relative order (inside the pairs) independently in $2^n$ ways. This produces the right-hand side.

Comment: For completeness' sake would you mind giving a small, clear explanation of the right hand side?

Comment: I have done so.

Comment: For the LHS, it need not be specified as to starting with "youngest" or any such attribute. It can be any line of *2n* people, then the 1st person has *(2n-1)* choices, the next person  now has *(2n-3)* choices and so on.